# Recursive directory listing of unicoded file names

Tags: unicode, cmd

If i use `dir /s /b>list.txt` all unicode characters in file names, like `äöüß`, are broken or missed - instead of `ä` i get `''`, `ü` just disappears and so on...

Yes, i know, unicode characters aren't a good way to name files - they aren't named by me.

Is there a method to get file names healthy listed?

Comment: You could try changing the [code page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) by [`chcp`](http://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html) (e. g., 437, 850, 1252, 65001, to name a few common ones). Additionally, you could try opening your command prompt using [`cmd /U`](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)...

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic, since it is not a programing question. Should be migrated to [Super User](http://superuser.com) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default console code page usually only supports a small subset of Unicode.  US Windows defaults to code page 437 and supports only 256 characters.

If you open a Unicode command prompt (`cmd /u`), when you redirect to a file the file will be encoded in UTF-16LE, which supports all Unicode characters.  Notepad should display the content as long as its font supports the glyphs used.

Changing to an encoding such as UTF-8 (`chcp 65001`) that supports the full Unicode code point set and redirecting to a file will use that encoding and work as well.